# how to use input in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i wrote a script in cmd (*.cmd) that copy some file to ftp server, its working and its fine. this is the code:

```
@echo off
```

# put the command lines in to txt file

```
echo cd wf/721/pages >> temp.txt

echo put C:\Users\tc99670\Desktop\tempwf\721\pages\channel.json >> temp.txt
echo put C:\Users\tc99670\Desktop\tempwf\721\pages\main-screen.json >> temp.txt
echo put C:\Users\tc99670\Desktop\tempwf\721\pages\settings.json >> temp.txt
echo put C:\Users\tc99670\Desktop\tempwf\721\pages\wihow to usefi.json >> temp.txt



echo quit >> temp.txt
```

# connect to ftp and running the all the command in the txt file

```
ftp -n -s:temp.txt 150.42.40.221
```

# deleting the txt file

```
del temp.txt
```

its working great but when i tried to add the user input option its not working any more:

```
@echo off
set /P path=Enter path:




echo cd wf/721/pages >> temp.txt

echo put %path%\721\pages\channel.json >> temp.txt
echo put %path%\721\pages\main-screen.json >> temp.txt
echo put %path%\721\pages\settings.json >> temp.txt
echo put %path%\721\pages\wifi.json >> temp.txt



echo quit >> temp.txt

ftp -n -s:temp.txt 150.42.40.221

del temp.txt
```

i dont know what went wrong, 
thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do ***not*** use **`path`** as a variable name...

...it is a system variable that tells `cmd` where to look for programs. Change `path` in this script to something else, such as `inputpath`.

Comment: If I could, I would make the first line of this answer larger, and bright red.